# Get List of JSON objects in Map

Tags: apex, lightning, json, map, aura-action

I am passing List attribute as a String to aura action by JSON.stringify

and this is what I am getting in the apex debug --

```
[{"minorDependent":"0032200000ADltqAAD","enrolledbyAdult":"0032200000ADlc1AAD"}]
```

This is a a list of JSON objects, 
however I am not able to deserialize into map--

I tried -

```
List<Map<String,Object>> lstMinorEnrolledBy = (List<Map<String,Object>>) JSON.deserialize(strMinorEnrolledBy, List<Map<String,Object>>.class);
```

Error message:

> Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

Comment: You should be trying to deserialize into a `List<Map<String,String>>`

Comment: You might like to try JSON.deserializeUntyped.

Comment: Yeah, that too!

Comment: I get this after trying your suggestions --Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

Comment: Strangely it goes to last debug line and I get this in debug--MVK lstMinorEnrolledBy-->({enrolledbyAdult=0032200000ADlc1AAD, minorDependent=0032200000ADltqAAD})

Comment: Ooops my bad I was reading the old logs... solved the issue thanks

Comment: @CasparHarmer You should consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: Ok.. just verifying in dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the target data type to `List<Map<String,String>>`

This works: (checked in dev console)

```
String str = '[{"minorDependent":"0032200000ADltqAAD","enrolledbyAdult":"0032200000ADlc1AAD"}]';
List<Map<String,String>> lstMinorEnrolledBy = (List<Map<String,String>>) JSON.deserialize(str, List<Map<String,String>>.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.deserializeUntyped if you had a case where there was a mix of String and Decimal values:

```
Object[] rows = (Object[])JSON.deserializeUntyped(strMinorEnrolledBy);
for(Object row: rows) {
    Map<String, Object> values = (Map<String, Object>)row;
    // you can now access values directly
}
```